# Pyramid FileResponse for dynamic files

Tags: pyramid

I want my client to download (not render) a dynamically generated PDF file via pyramid.  Right now I do it like this:

```
def get_pdf(request):
    pdfFile = open('/tmp/example.pdf', "wb")
    pdfFile.write(generator.GeneratePDF())

    response = FileResponse('/tmp/example.pdf')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment;  filename=example.pdf')
    return response
```

From the client point-of-view it's exactly what I need.  However,

1. It leaves behind an orphaned file
2. It isn't thread-safe (though I could use random filenames)

The [docs](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileResponse) say:

> class FileResponse
>
> A Response object that can be used to serve a static file from disk simply.

So `FileResponse` is probably not what I should be using.  How would you replace it with something more dynamic but indistinguishable for the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a normal response with the same header:

```
def get_pdf(request):
    response = Response(body=generator.GeneratePDF())
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment;filename=example.pdf')
    return response
```